# C# - Random number with seed

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

I have this code:

```
var rand = new Random(0);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(rand.Next(0, 100));
}
```

And program should give me 100 times the same number (because seed is the same), but it gives different numbers...
Why?

Edit:
When I will do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(new Random(0).Next);
}
```

That returns the same number every time. That means, seed is changing? If yes, how? Is it increasing?

Comment: Next progresses the random number generator to generate a new random. In your example, you seed once and call 100 Next();

Comment: The seed is just...the seed - how the algorithm is initialized.  `Next` will give you different numbers, but that sequence would be the same with a new random using the same seed

Comment: If you want 100 times same number, then why use `Random` class

Comment: Yes - the 100 numbers you get will be "random," but they will match every time you start with the same seed. Not x repeated 100 times, but x(1)-x(100) repeated each time For/Next is run

Comment: Move `var rand = new Random(0);` into the `for` block and you will see that the same number is produced with every call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: (on your latest edit) How would that be changing the seed? You hard coded `0` in the constructor?? If you want it as random as possible then do not pass in anything, the system clock will provide a value.

Comment: AFTEREDIT: because you are only calling NEXT once in your second example - you are re-seeding every loop

Comment: First example: 1 seed next*100 second example 100 seeds next*1 each seed

Comment: How is generated next seed?

Comment: You should really read the documentation: [System.Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is usually confused the other way around.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should not give you 100 same numbers but it should give you exactly the same 100 numbers each time you restart the app.

Seed is used to make random predictable. Imagine multiplayer game where you want something to be random. But you want to make sure that this random behaves the same for each player/client. And `seed` is the way to go here.

Comment: Seed is increasing or what?

Comment: Seed defines sequence of random number that will be generated. The same sequence is generated for the same seed.

Comment: Ok, I understand.
Thanks for help

Comment: I have last question - is this sequence repeatable or infinite?
I mean if I will call "Next(0, 100)" many times, will sequence go again from start?

(Sorry for my English)

Comment: @TheChilliPL it shouldn't, basically; although that is not a strict guarantee. It is not an inbuilt expectation that it should restart unless you create a new `Random` with the original seed

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: I have another question - can I find nth random number from seed?